# Pre select a lookupedit item by the value member

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Lets say I have one LookUpEdit with this configuration: `ValueMember="ID" DisplayMember="Description"` so when the form are loaded I need to pre select the item that have 1 in the ID column. How can I do that?

Comment: maybe `SelectedValue = 1`

Comment: @Plutonix I can't find that option

Comment: I guess it's one of these :https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic, not part of the .NET framework

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `EditValue`

```
LookupEdit1.EditValue = 1
```

See https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q37765

Comment: Well what I do is obtain de ID using some logic and pass that ID as you say in the `EditValue` but the item with that ID are not selected and I don't know why.

Comment: What is the Type of ID?

Comment: Integer and even if I pass a direct number the item are not selected

Comment: The only way that work to pre select some item is using the `ItemIndex` propertie but the items doesn't have the ID in order is something like `4,0,1,2,5,etc`